# test switch on information in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I want to test shut down and switch on information in junit.

```
public void shutDownState(Context cxt) {
    Log.d(TAG, "in shutdown fun");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    shutDownTime = sdfDateTime1.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        long swithchoffdata;
        if (!"00:00:00.000".equals(dsd.getLastRecord())) {
            swithchoffdata = dsd.insert(shutDownTime.toString(),
                    switchOnTime);
            Log.d(TAG, "switchoffdata: " + swithchoffdata);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Swithch off error: ");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "swith off: " + dsd.selectAll());
}

public void swithOnState() {
    Log.d("appcheck", "switch on func");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    switchOnTime = sdfDateTime1.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dsd.updateLastRecord(switchOnTime);
    Log.d("appcheck", "switch on: " + dsd.selectAll());
}
```

These are my methods in actual project. What I should do actually in my test class to unit test this methods. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a template that might work.  There are a lot of unanswered questions about your code.  Are these methods in an `Activity`, for example?  I assume so.  I recommend the `AndroidTestCase` as it doesn't launch the activity and so consumes much less overhead and runs faster.  The `AndroidTestCase` provides an `mContext` member variable so that you can pass the context to your `shutDownState()` method.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

import com.example.YourActivity;

public class YourActivityTest extends AndroidTestCase
{

  private YourActivity mActivity;

  protected void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = new YourActivity();
    // whatever else you need
  }

  protected void tearDown() throws Exception
  {
    super.tearDown();

    // whatever else you need
  }

  public void testShutDownState()
  {
    mActivity.shutDownState(mContext); // mContext is a dummy context provided
                                   // by AndroidTestCase
    // put some asserts here to confirm correct operation
  }

  public void testSwithOnState()// note: you misspelled switch
  {
    mActivity.swithOnState();

    // put some asserts here to confirm correct operation
  }

}
```

You can check your class member variables (such as `switchOnTime`) using asserts after the call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank for your help .actually this code is in my service class.can you suggest me any good resource for unit test using junit in android

Comment: Yes.  Besides the stuff on developer.android.com, there is a great blog at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html.  It is maintained by the author of a book you may want to read, "Android Application Testing Guide".